# generate string from list Using factorial python

Tags: python

I have list of words like this

```
words = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
]
```

I want to create `new list` like this

```
new_list = [
    'A-B-C',
    'A-C-B',
    'B-A-C',
    'B-C-A',
    'C-A-B',
    'C-B-A',
]
```

I want to create this `new_list` using `Factorial Formula`

The actual `words` list contains up to **50** items

Comment: Your computer doesn't have enough memory for that list when you have 50 items.

Comment: do you want only with Factorial Formula?

Comment: I use the google colab

Comment: @user1740577 yes

Comment: do you have try anything? send your code

Comment: google colab doesn't have enough memory, either.

Comment: @user1740577 doesn't matter, I just want to create this list

Comment: because you say no matter , edit your question and delete this sentence : `create this new_list using Factorial Formula`

Comment: please check and see this solution run correctly on colab or not, and say to me

Answer (score 1):

python represent letters as UTF-8 which takes at minimum 1 byte to represent a character or 4 at maximum. The number of different combinations in your program will be equal to `50!` which exactly =

```
30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

which is equal to `2^214` which is in best case scenario in which 1 byte will be used to store 1 character, the total storage will be `5 * 2^214` which is simply huge and no there is no memory that can deal with this type of size.